# Access "Encountered an error" when outputting a query to Excel

Tags: ms-access, vba, export-to-excel

We have a long established Access application which exports a query to Excel using this syntax:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryFoo", "Microsoft Excel (*.xls)", "Bar.xlt", True
```

This has worked for years.

Today a customer with Access 2002 10.4302.4219 SP-2 (Excel is the same) has reported that it's stopped working. The database reports that it "Encountered an error" etc and dies.

This problem applies to all three PCs using this application.

At first, upon checking the file `Bar.xlt` and finding that it had corrupted (it reports `Invalid file format` if you try and open it standalone) we thought we had a solution, which was to slot in a good version of `Bar.xlt` and go again. This results in the same error, .. in fact recorrupting `Bar.xlt` in the process.

We've tried the following variations (in case it doesn't like the fact that it's an xlt, or that it needs the explicit `acFormatXLS` format but we still get the problem (in any case, the original syntax has worked for years).

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryFoo", "Microsoft Excel (*.xls)", "Bar.xls", True    
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryFoo", acFormatXLS, "Bar.xlt", True    
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, "qryFoo", acFormatXLS, "Bar.xls", True
```

We've also compacted/repaired both front end and back end, of course. No change.

The only other thing to note is, while working, I saw this:

[image]

and did wonder if this indicated some general problem with Office on this machine.

But of course that could be unrelated.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried repairing the office installation from the control panel? I've had some really odd errors using access and excel that have required a simple repair to fix.